# Nested function in programing

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am reading Newton's method in SICP, where he introduce the block structure which have the function nested, say

```
(define (sqrt x)
    (define (good enough ? guess x)
             (<(abs(-(square guess) x)) 0.001))
    (define (improve guess x)
             (average guess (/ x guess)))
    (define (sqrt-iter guess x)
        (if (good-enough? guess x)
        guess
        (sqrt-iter(improve guess x)x))) 
(sqrt-iter 1.0 x))
```

I am quite confused because in my understanding of nested, "good enough ?" and "improve guess" should be nested
in the body of "sqrt-iter", and "sqrt iter" should be put in the body of "sqrt x"

```
(define (sqrt x)
   (sqrt-iter 1.0 x
      (define (sqrt-iter guess x)
        (if (good-enough? guess x)
        guess
        (sqrt-iter(improve guess x)x)
             (define (good enough ? guess x)
                 (<(abs(-(square guess) x)) 0.001))
             (define (improve guess x)
                 (average guess (/ x guess)))
       )) 
    ))
```

why it is not like that.I am using LISP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `sqrt-iter` *is* already defined inside the body of `sqrt`. But the way you wrote it doesn't make sense, you're trying to call `sqrt-iter` but you're defining it inside the call as a third parameter. This isn't right:

```
(sqrt-iter 1.0 x (define (sqrt-iter ...)))
```

You *must* define it before calling it, and you *can't* define it as if it were a parameter, as part of the procedure call. This is the correct way:

```
(define (sqrt-iter guess x) ...) ; first define
(sqrt-iter 1.0 x) ; after defining, you can call it
```

Your other suggestion makes more sense, it'd be possible to define `good-enough?` and `improve` inside `sqrt-iter`, but maybe it's clearer in the way they wrote it in the book. This is valid, but has the disadvantage that `good-enough?` and `improve` will be redefined each time `sqrt-iter` is called:

```
(define (sqrt x)
  (define (sqrt-iter guess x)
    (define (good-enough? guess x)
      (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))
    (define (improve guess x)
      (average guess (/ x guess)))
    (if (good-enough? guess x)
        guess
        (sqrt-iter (improve guess x)x))) 
  (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))
```

You should read more carefully the section of the book that explains how procedures are defined and used in Scheme, you seem to be confusing concepts, mixing parameters, procedure definitions and procedure invocations.

Comment: so what about  "good enough ?" and "improve guess", it can be put under the define of "sqrt-iter" but not inside the body, why he doesn't put "good enough ?" and "improve guess" under "sqrt-iter"

Comment: @89085731 I updated my answer, those are ok to move, but still I prefer the original version, as it appears in the book - it's easier to read.

Comment: My worry is that if we don't put "good enough' and "improve guess" under "sqrt-iter", then these two functions lie on the same layer of "sqrt-iter" but not the relation of nested

Comment: it looks like for nested function, it can be treated as some kind of hidden variable, so we need to call it before use it

Comment: Don't worry about nesting ;) use it only if by doing so you can avoid some parameters when defining new procedures. And be careful how you nest procedures, the definitions should be only at the start of the procedure, not in arbitrary places.